# Move Rigidbody2D while mouse drag

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

I am new to unity 3d game engine.I am creating a wood pattern puzzle game.I want to move small parts of wood according to the mouse position. I'm using the rigidbody2D. While moving I also want to detect collision from another wood parts and any other obstacle. Please help me out.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. Please provide the code with what you've tried so far.

Comment: What should happen if the player tries to move something into an other object?

Answer (score 0):

You script would probably look something like this (it depends on the precise functionality you're looking for):

```
#pragma strict

private var moveWithMouse : boolean = false;
private var lastMousePosition : Vector3;

function Update()
{
    var changeInMousePosition : Vector3 = Vector3(0,0,0);
    if (lastMousePosition != null)
    {
       changeInMousePosition = Input.mousePosition-lastMousePosition;
    }
    lastMousePosition = Input.mousePosition;
    if (moveWithMouse)
    {
        transform.position += Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(changeInMousePosition) - Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Vector3(0,0,0));
    }
}

function OnMouseDown()
{
    moveWithMouse = true;
}

function OnMouseUp()
{
    moveWithMouse = false;
}
```

Here are all the documentation pages that explain the fancy parts of the code above.

> http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnMouseDown.html
>   http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnMouseUp.html
>   http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input-mousePosition.html
>   http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera.ScreenToWorldPoint.html

If there's anything in the code that's new to you and not covered in the documentation pages (such as Vector3, Transform, the Update function etc..) then you'd benefit from visiting a beginner's guide to unity before attempting a project.

https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/modules/beginner/live-training-archive/coding-for-the-absolute-beginner

---

In order to use my script, you must:

- Create a GameObject (the one you want to be draggable)
- Add a sprite renderer to it (and select the image you want for it)
- Add a 2d collider (polygon2d for precision, circle2d or box2d for speed)
- Create a new script and add it to the GameObject

Learning how to use Unity's editor might even be more essential than the programming itself when it comes to creating and customizing your own game, so if you don't know how to do the things above (create **GameObject**, and add **Components**) you should refer to a beginners guide to the Unity editor.

Here's a set of tutorial pages about Unity's editor:
http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UnityBasics.html

Here's the page I think is most important:
http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UnityBasics.html

---

Hope this helps. Cheers

Comment: Bear in mind, the code is untested. I don't know if it'll work, but it should get you started. Contact me if you have unfixable issues